# How can I do a fast-forward merge using the GitHub API?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, github-api

I'm setting up a Jenkins pipeline script and using API calls to GitHub to perform merges and releases after tests pass.

For my intended workflow, I need to use the Jenkinsfile to merge my `release-candidate` branch into my `beta-release` branch. This merge should always be a fast-forward merge, since this is the only way work ever gets onto the `beta-release` branch. It's important that a merge commit is not created, because I check GitHub statuses on the latest commit in that branch to see if tests are up to date.

I tried the [merge API call](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/), but it always creates a merge commit.

I tried creating a [PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) and then merging it with the rebase strategy, but that created a merge commit as well.

Is it possible to perform a fast-forward merge using the GitHub API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually do a ref update instead of merge.

```
status=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" -X PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/${REPO}/git/refs/heads/${BASE} \
-d '{  "sha": $(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/${REPO}/git/refs/heads/${HEAD} | jq .object.sha ),  "force": false  }')
# In case of non-fast-forward case create a pull request
if (( $status != 200 )); then 
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/${REPO}/pulls \
   -d '{  "title": "Great pull request", "body": "Please check this non-fast-forward merge", "head": "${HEAD}",  "base": "${BASE}"  }'
fi;
params:
  REPO, BASE, HEAD, GITHUB_TOKEN
```

Comment: spot on! For more info on the API for next good soul:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-reference